# SwiftUI force child view to redraw

Tags: swiftui

I have a modal view with a child view, with in itself has another child view. When I rotate the device, the first child view need to get redrawn to pass new GeometricReader data to the last child.

I'm detecting the rotation by Notification Center in the view model

```
    @objc func updateView(_ : Notification) {
        self.refresh.toggle()
        self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
```

The view model has two properties.

```
        @Published var objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
        @Published var refresh: Bool
```

In the view I have a @observedObject vm, but when the vm changes the view doesn't redraw. The first child need to redraw to send it's size to the second child for some line drawings that need to be re-aligned.

[Edit]

```
struct StackView: View {
@ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel()

var body: some View {
    
    Color.white
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            Text("Hello StackView")
            View2()
        }
    }
}
}

extension StackView {
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateView(_:)), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func updateView(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
}

struct View2: View {

var body: some View {
    Text("Hello view 2")
        .overlay(GeometryReader { geo in
            Color.clear
                .onAppear {
                    print(geo.frame(in: .global))
                }
        })
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason in that notification usage at all. What's the goal - layout is updated automatically on rotation?

Comment: As you say, the rotation is looked after, but I need to get view2 to redraw.  There are lines connected to images on that view, and when they move due to the rotation, they need to get the updated values.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     @Published var objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
> ```

remove this line. `ObservableObject` has default implementation of publisher for `objectWillChange` property, so just use it, like

```
@objc func updateView(_ : Notification) {
   self.objectWillChange.send()
}
```

and if you don't have special meaning for `var refresh: Bool` then it is also not needed.

Comment: It still doesn't play ball. View A doesn't redraw (I should see the GeometryReader print some values), which mean that View B doesn't either. (again there are GeometryReaders that should print values)

Comment: Would you provide some minimal reproducible code? I assume there is something missed in original question. Btw, GeometryReader does not require force update, it changes dimensions automatically, so if you don't hardcode anything, then internals should update without intervention. It looks like a reason somewhere in other code.

Comment: There are some hardcoded shapes in View2 that take in values from the frame, hence I need to redraw it to update those values.